# pyCURL segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, segmentation-fault, pycurl

I'm trying to send a POST request to an HTTPS url using Python's pyCURL (curl port to python). The problem is that my script exits with segmentation fault, which happens only for the particular URL. For other URLs (either HTTP or HTTPS) it works fine. Also, if I use command-line curl or urllib2 the request is successful.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pycurl
from urllib import urlencode

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://monitoring.ad-sy.ch/cgi-bin/lg.cgi')
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0) 
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)

post_data = {'router': 'rt-adsy-becs-01','protocol':'IPv4','addr':'198.41.208.143','query':'trace'}

storage = StringIO()

# Form data must be provided already urlencoded.
postfields = urlencode(post_data)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)


c.perform()
c.close()

content = storage.getvalue()
print content
```

When I remove the SSL options `c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)` and `c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)` it doesn't throw a segmentation fault error but it throws the following exception:

`pycurl.error: (51, 'gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized')`

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to recommend [`requests`](http://python-requests.org).

Comment: Yes`requests` is nice, but I run into problems when the server sets wrong Content-range headers in chunked responses, and as a result I was getting partial responses.